# Kentico sync and AD authentication

Tags: x509, kentico

My target site needs AD auth to browse and use the admin portal. All is fine there. This means syncing to this server via username and password authentication doesn't work. Does this mean i need to enable x.509 authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean using the Staging Module, the staging module's "Username and password" really is not linked to the actual CMS Users.  You can put whatever Username and Password on the Destination server, and connect to it from the Source.

x.509 is also fine.

Tell me if you aren't talking about the Staging Module though.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do 1 of 2 things:

- Enable [mixed mode authentication](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/configuring-windows-ad-authentication/configuring-mixed-mode-authentication).  Yes the overall authentication doesn't need to use a physical `cms_user` user but since you have AD Authentication enabled, anytime another user or service tries to access a system page it may require them to log in.
- [Create a web.config location node](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/316871/how-to-control-authorization-permissions-in-an-asp.net-application) in your `/CMSPages/Staging/web.config` file that excludes anyone or everyone to access a the SyncServer.asmx page within there.

Otherwise configure the x.509 certificate setup.